# Correct usage of MVC route id parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to do the following in asp.net mvc:

```
myquizsite.com/quizzes              - list quizzes available
myquizsite.com/quizzes/quiz1        - list previous instances of quiz1
myquizsite.com/quizzes/quiz2        - list previous instances of quiz2
myquizsite.com/quizzes/quiz1/create - create new quiz1
```

Using the default route, this would mean that the "create" parameter gets passed into the action quiz1 to create a new instance of it.

This seems odd to me so I am guessing there is a better way of doing it, though I am not sure how.

Comment: Show the controller methods your trying to call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MVC Attribute routing

```
public QuizzesController :Controller
{
   [Route("quizzes/{id?}")]
   public ActionResult Index(string id="")
   {
     if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
     {
       //to do  :Return quizzes available
     } 
     else
     {
       //To do :Return previous instances of id passed(Ex :quiz1/quiz2)
     }
   }
   [Route("quizzes/{id}/create")]
   public ActionResult Create(string id)
   {
      // to do  : return Create view for Id passed (Ex :quiz1/quiz2)
   }
}
```

You can enable attribute routing in the `RegisterRoutes` method in  RouteConfig.cs  file.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{            
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //This line enables attribute routing 
   //Default Route definition goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I am after.

Comment: i was assuming attribute routing is came with mvc 6, thank you!